Does anyone know where i can find a gemara menukad that isnt 13” i would like something more condensed like a 6 volume 10” with the vowels
I've been searching all over for a gemara set with the vowels in a small size. All I see are the 13” ones over many volumes.
Does any one know of 6-volume fully vowelized set? Or would that have to be a custom order from somewhere?

Steinzeltz gemara is too big?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

You can custom make it yourself, but not for all of shas yet.

Go to Sefaria, under Talmud choose which Masechta you want.
on the bottom right of the page you should see option to download text, choose vocalized
Open in word and edit to your liking (I wrote myself a quick guide for a decent looking meforash here, should apply to Talmud too, you can try to make it Tzurat Hadaf with this tool)
Save as PDF, get it printed on Lulu.com (Amazon KDP is cheaper but does not allow private books, the vocalized talmud on sefaria is only available on a non commercial license).

